# Wordpress on docker-compose no run

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: example
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

the services run normally, but, a  few seconds later, the wordpress container stop.

This is my docker logs wordpress container:

```
WordPress not found in /var/www/html - copying now...
Complete! WordPress has been successfully copied to /var/www/html

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 10

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 10

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 10

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 10


MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 10

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 10

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 10

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 10
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: you should show logs of wordpress container using `docker logs <dockerl_id_container>`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan I edit my question, that is docker logs wordpress container

Comment: what `host` parameter do you use for mysql connection in wordpress source code ?

Comment: I took this example reference in docker-compose section https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/

Answer (score 9):

**Solution:**

Remember to link the mysql container to the wordpress container:

```
links:
   - db:mysql
```

Like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - db:mysql
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: example
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

This important detail is not mentioned on the [WordPress image official Dockerhub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/)

Comment: The `mysql` host alias in the link is important here :(

Answer (score 5):

This [anwser](https://serverfault.com/a/880777/368226) works for me, cause I didn't have enough reputation to vote that anwser, I copy it here:

```yaml
depends_on:
  - db
```

That just makes sure the database container is fully loaded before the `wordpress` container. You need to tell docker to link the `db` container from the `wordpress` container to reference it by name.

What `docker-compose` does under the hood is take the ip docker gives the `db`container and add a `/etc/hosts` entry to the `wordpress` container so you can reference it by name.

So try adding this to the wordpress section

```yaml
links:
  - db
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you setting the DB host (and other needed MySql attributes), in your Compose file wordpress service (other than password, shown in your post)? e.g.:

```
environment:
  WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: example
  WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
  WORDPRESS_DB_USER: {xxx}
  WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: {xxx}
  WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: {xxx}
```

In particular the "host" value, which in your setup should be `db`. You should not have to do any linking, although it would be a good idea to add

```
depends_on:
  - db
```

to your wordpress service block which will set the dependency order to start the db container before your wordpress container. (A `links` attribute would do the same, but trying to keep things simple.)

Note:

> **By default Compose sets up a single network for your app**. Each
> container for a service joins the default network and is both
> reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by
> them at a hostname identical to the container name.
>
> **Links** allow you to define extra aliases by which a service is
> reachable from another service. They are **not required** to enable
> services to communicate - **by default, any service can reach any other
> service at that service’s name**.
>
> > https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#/links

I would not mess around with networks unless you really understand what you are doing, as in most cases the defaults will work fine. If you have some special case, you can always optimize that later.

Answer (score 1):

Adding these under 'db:' solved it for me.

```
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not use yml, but had same logs and this did not work

```
docker run -dP --link elated_yonath -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=libik -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=prdik wordpress
```

But then I found, that I have to add :mysql to linked container

```
docker run -dP --link elated_yonath:mysql -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=libik -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=prdik wordpress
```

Now it started.

Answer (score 0):

As said earlier you should add

```
depends_on:
  - db
```

but after this I still getting message about connection problem. And only this clear problem - second option:

```
networks:
    local:
```

This solve error 
**PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in Standard input code on line 22**