# WordPress docker compose won't start mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

I am trying to set up a docker container for WordPress development using `docker-compose.yml` which looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: root
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data # Required if importing an existing database
      - ./:/var/www/html # Theme development
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: root
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3306:80
volumes:
  data: {}
```

And I'm getting errors like this:

```
wordpress_1   | Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 22
wordpress_1   | 
wordpress_1   | Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 22
wordpress_1   | 
wordpress_1   | MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

I tried clearing my images and containers but no luck. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: you don't have to supply the port on WORDPRESS_DB_HOST

Comment: Nope, that didn't help

Comment: Probably you need to provide port in your `db` service

Comment: Will try that. It's odd since the same setup works for a colleague of mine :S

Answer (score 0):

Try providing links option for both wordpress and phpmyadmin.

```
links:
  - db:mysql
```

Edit: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407117/wordpress-on-docker-compose-no-run) question. Add mysql to the db. I don't if this solves, I have to try out once I go home later.

Comment: Sadly still getting the same error. I tried restarting the docker, deleting images and containers, nothing changes.