# Unknown authentication method error while using wordpress and mysql docker images

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

I am trying to install wordpress with mysql via docker but I have communication errors between the container of the DB and the wordpress container.

here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:latest
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     links:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes: 
    db_data:
```

If I execute the "docker-compose up -d" command and that I open the logs of the wordpress container I have this error:

```
...
wordpress_1  | Warning: mysqli::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_1  |
wordpress_1  | Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress_1  |
wordpress_1  | MySQL Connection Error: (2054) The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
...
```

I added command: '--default-authentication plugin=mysql_native_password'  in the db section and i changed the mysql version to 5.7 but it did not help me solve the problem.
I also visited these discussions :

[Wordpress on docker-compose no run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407117/wordpress-on-docker-compose-no-run)

https://serverfault.com/questions/880773/unable-to-access-wordpress-site-created-as-a-docker-stack/880777#880777

https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/313

Thank you in advance for your proposals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that WordPress/PHP [doesn't support](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/313#issuecomment-401049241) MySQL v8 yet. Even `wordpress` docker image readme [suggests to use](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) MySQL v5.7. After changing mysql version to v5.7, you might notice that MySQL container crashes with an error similar to below:

```
...
db_1         | 2019-01-28T18:45:24.611045Z 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Table flags are 0 in the data dictionary but the flags in file ./ibdata1 are 0x4800!
db_1         | 2019-01-28 18:45:24 0x7f00e013a740  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139641736111936 in file ut0ut.cc line 942
db_1         | InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
...
```

To fix this, easiest way is to delete the MySQL docker volume using `docker-compose down -v`. After that, `docker-compose up -d` should work.

If that still doesn't work, use the docker-compose example from https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/. Adding it here in case it gets pulled down in future.

> ```
> version: '3.1'
>
> services:
>
>   wordpress:
>     image: wordpress
>     restart: always
>     ports:
>       - 8080:80
>     environment:
>       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
>       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
>       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
>       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb
>
>   db:
>     image: mysql:5.7
>     restart: always
>     environment:
>       MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
>       MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
>       MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
>       MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much, however, I tried to do what you suggested but without success. in the end I copied paste the example provided on this page https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/

Comment: I was able to get it working with these steps. But glad to know that you got it working using that example. :) I've edited the answer to include that example too for the benefit of others coming here later.

Comment: @kasko Referring to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54443057/docker-containers-restart-fails#comment95695723_54443137), you should be able to add volumes. If you get an error where `InnoDB` crashes with logs similar to above (this might happen once due to MySQL version changing from v8 to v5.7), try doing `docker-compose down -v` to remove the containers and volumes. And then `docker-compose up -d` to start the services.

Comment: I already did it and as I said it did not work. Or maybe I did it badly. Do you have a sample configuration?

Comment: Yes. I just changed `mysql:latest` to `mysql:5.7` in the configuration you added in the question and was able to get it working with `docker-compose down -v` and `docker-compose up`.