# Docker containers restart fails

Tags: docker, containers

Hello I have 2 docker container: one for wordpress and the other for the DB. I want to copy html and php files in the wordpress container for that I saw that it must first stop the container otherwise the copy will not be done. Except that after the copy in the container if I do :

```
docker restart $(docker ps -a -q)
```

I have this error :

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container 035714167b27: network 87e28d3e4121e59f1a3dab6e0afc81db6f273e2585fe22045f3dcd7edcd3ae5d not found
Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container 2169bed03e64: network 87e28d3e4121e59f1a3dab6e0afc81db6f273e2585fe22045f3dcd7edcd3ae5d not found
```

And even if I restart the containers one by one I have the error : for example :

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container 035714167b27: network 87e28d3e4121e59f1a3dab6e0afc81db6f273e2585fe22045f3dcd7edcd3ae5d not found
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    networks:
      - database
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ******
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    networks:
      - database
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '********'
networks:
  database:
```

Error for docker-compose up command :

```
Starting wordpress_db_1        ... error
Starting wordpress_wordpress_1 ...

Starting wordpress_wordpress_1 ... error

ERROR: for wordpress_wordpress_1  Cannot start service wordpress: network 87e28d3e4121e59f1a3dab6e0afc81db6f273e2585fe22045f3dcd7edcd3ae5d not found

ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: network 87e28d3e4121e59f1a3dab6e0afc81db6f273e2585fe22045f3dcd7edcd3ae5d not found

ERROR: for wordpress  Cannot start service wordpress: network 87e28d3e4121e59f1a3dab6e0afc81db6f273e2585fe22045f3dcd7edcd3ae5d not found
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

And for  docker-compose down command :

```
Removing wordpress_wordpress_1 ... done
Removing wordpress_db_1        ... done
Removing network wordpress_database
```

Output of the docker network ls command:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                  DRIVER              SCOPE
13f1e50b9b01        nat                   nat                 local
82f0375abab2        nat                   nat                 local
9b6e4eb573bd        none                  null                local
3c58f55f0ae6        wordpress_database    nat                 local
90581f5a1c1d        wordpress_default     nat                 local
03cc07eda9e8        wordpress_wordpress   nat                 local
```

**Information :**

1. Windows 10
2. Docker Version 2.0.0.2 (30215)

Thank you in advance !!!

Comment: can you run a `docker network ls` to inspect the networks? If you are using docker compose, you should be stopping and restarting the containers with the docker compose CLI too. Anyway you could include the files you are trying to copy before starting the container using a volume (https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). Volumes can be defined in the compose file too (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes)

Comment: If you're using docker-compose, I'd prefer to use `docker-compose` commands rather than `docker` directly. Does `docker-compose restart` work?

Comment: No it does not work

Comment: Does `docker-compose down` or `docker-compose up` work?

Comment: docker-compose down work but not docker-compose up

Comment: @kasko It would be easier for others to answer the question if you could update the question with the results from these commands.

Comment: I have updated the question you can read it again to see. I also added the output of the docker network ls command

Comment: I have the impression that the network is deleted once the containers are stopped

Comment: Maybe try deleting all the containers and try again as described [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2194#issuecomment-408679922). If that still doesn't work, I'd suggest to do `docker system prune` and try starting the services again.

Answer (score 1):

You are using docker compose for starting?
If so, probably the network is removed when the last container of a network exits.
I would not copy the files manuelly, use a volume binding, that should remove the need to copy files into a container, which is a huge red flag

Comment: Yes I use docker-compose.
The problem is that if I add volumes I have a connection problem between wordpress and DB. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54405497/unknown-authentication-method-error-while-using-wordpress-and-mysql-docker-image